# Floating semi-transparent image for comparison

Tags: macos, applications, graphics

I'm a web developer on a Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) and was wondering if there is a (free) alternative to [Overlay2](http://www.colinthomas.com/overlay/) - basically it's an app that lets you create a floating window with a semi-transparent image on it that you can use for direct reference - I plan on using it to match my output code to what the designer had in mind, pixel by pixel. I often just move between tabs real fast but the position isn't the same and my eyes can only be that precise.

I just don't want to have to pay $25 for such a simple functionality.

Comment: Amazing how many people want to get paid by their clients but the software developers who write the tools to get the job done don't. Consider how much easier your job is with Overlay, how much time it saves, and then question how $25 compares.

Comment: To be honest, a piece of software that only does this, is not worth $25. That's way overpriced. If it were $5 or less I would buy it. Also, it wasn't exactly great for all my needs, especially the focus scheme and such, as the window would lose focus on certain conditions. So yes, I was looking for a free alternative that does about the same thing. Either way as the years passed, I found myself not using anything of the sorts and changing my work methods to be better. So, I ended up not wasting $25 :)

Comment: It is work $25 if it saves that much of your time. For a worthwhile developer that is less than an hours work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this application I just came accross: http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

Comment: Afloat does not work on macOS 10.14 (Mojave). The application is now hosted here: https://github.com/rwu823/afloat

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few more:

- [Uberlayer](http://twelvetwenty.nl/apps/uberlayer)
- [GluePrint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/glueprint/id736042993)
- [Overlay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overlay/id653092846)

More alternatives (also for Windows) on [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/overlay2/)

Comment: Uber layer is nice.... :)

Answer (score 2):

For any web development purposes or when working in any web app you can use a browser extension like the [PerfectPixel by WellDoneCode](https://www.welldonecode.com/perfectpixel/). It's free and supports multiple overlays.