# How does one install "afloat" on OS 10.8/Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

On OS X, I want to show an always-foregrounded, transparent image while working on the application underneath it, for tracing purposes. As mentioned in [this other stackexchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94944/floating-semi-transparent-image-for-comparison), the solution is the application called [afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/).

Great, so how do I get it to work? The old domain now just redirects to a [github project page](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/). There is **no** README, and there are **no** installation instructions. I found a [closed/wontfix "how to install" ticket](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/issues/6), and pieced together some probable instructions. This is what I have so far:

1. Download the SIMBL [zip file](http://www.culater.net/dl/files/SIMBL-0.9.9.zip)
2. Unzip the file
3. Double-click/install `SIMBL-0.9.9.pkg`
4. Create SIMBL bundle dir: `mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/`
5. Reboot
6. Install from the git repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/millenomi/afloat.git
$ cd afloat
$ xcodebuild -configuration Release install
  # verbose output trimmed, except for last line:
  ** INSTALL SUCCEEDED **
$ mv /tmp/Afloat.dst/Users/`whoami`/Library/Bundles/Afloat.bundle/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/
```

So now what? Did I do this correctly? Am I supposed to see additional "Window" menu options?

Comment: I tried building this, but was getting the message, "error: garbage collection is no longer supported". I found some discussion on another project explaining that Apple was deprecating garbage collection (https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/435) because they want people to transition to automatic reference counting (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)

Comment: On Yosemite 10.10.2 with XCode 6.11 I get 8 of these `error: garbage collection is no longer supported`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this did work. I did find that my X11 app had the extra Afloat options in the Window menu. Reading around, it seems it only works on Cocoa apps, so I guess X11 is Cocoa but nothing else is.

I also found a [downloadable dmg installer](http://afloat.en.softonic.com/mac/download). I'll try this out too.

Comment: Yeah, the Cocoa apps only is a huge pain :-(

Comment: FYI: The installer also installs a spam-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to install it on Mavericks and couldn't get any of the above instructions or downloads to work. I found a compiled download linked from this helpful article at http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/master-windows-afloat-mac which links to an installer (currently version 2.4) at http://mac.majorgeeks.com/files/details/afloat.html

The instructions and downloads worked great and all is well on Mavericks.